# About php's string in "\0" and ""?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $str1 = "";                    
    $str2 = "\0";                  
    var_dump(ord($str1), ord($str2));
    var_dump(strlen($str1), strlen($str2), $str1 === $str2);
    debug_zval_dump($str1, $str2);
?>
```

**Result:**

---

int(0)
  int(0)
  int(0)
  int(1)
  bool(false)
  string(0) "" refcount(2)
  string(1) "" refcount(2)
*Why the results are not consistent?*
*This is why ?*
*Who can answer me.3Q~*

Comment: What's you question exactly? I guess you are surprised by the result, otherwise you would not be posting a question, so can you tell what you expected?

Comment: yeah.Why the results are not consistent？They have the same ASCII code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct, ord() is expecting a character to be passed, and because you pass an empty string, it just assumes a NULL character (\0). Php strings are not null terminated, you can have perfectly legal strings with null characters within them.

To PHP a '\0' is just a string with one character in it.

Edit:

A PHP string is stored as list of all the characters in the string, and the total length. This allows PHP to store any character value, from 0 to 255. C Strings use the NULL character to determine where the string ends, PHP only uses the length to determine how long the string is.

Comment: You're right,but php strings seem binary safe. The strlen  also is binary-safe function.

Comment: "PHP strings are not null terminated" is false.  Every string (zend_string) in PHP stores its length separately so that binary data can be stored but PHP _also_ allocates an extra byte to NULL terminate the string (\0) so that it is safe to pass to C library and system functions that expect a pointer to a NULL terminated string.  When PHP docs talk about "binary safe" strings, this is actually what it is talking about:  The string is safe to use in all possible contexts.

Comment: @CubicleSoft That is an implementation detail though, you cannot see this as a PHP developer. The only time you may need to know or see this is as a native extension author, or if you work on the C source for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is built on C and null-bytes (\0) denote the end of a string in C, I would say it's something to do with that. PHP.net has an article on null bytes and the issues they can cause:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.nullbytes.php

Comment: No. That only pertains filesystem and other system functions. PHP strings itself are binary-safe, not suspect to NUL bytes.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php     A few functions, said in this manual not to be “binary safe”, may hand off the strings to libraries that ignore data after a NUL byte.

Comment: I try strcmp, a binary safe string comparison function, strcmp("", "\0") ==> -1 , This means ord and strlen functions are not binary safe function ??